# Facebook API profile picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a website for my Students Organization.
On that website there is a page where I list all the people who helped organize our Activities. Theres a picture of every member there.
To get the images, I used their facebook profile pictures.
I used http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/picture?height=250&width=250

This code did work a few days ago, but now the images dont seem to load. I followed the url and got a JSON object:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (user.name)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

So it seems to me that facebook might have changed their security... (after googling I found out about some changes in their API 2.0 but I didnt fully understand that..)
This link does still seem to work if you have the userID, but I'm unable to get that userID because of the same error message through graph.facebook.com...

Is there still a way to get facebook profile pictures of people on your website or did facebook totally block this off??

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the data, you'll need to implement Facebook Login for your website, where the users can give their permissions to your app to use their data.

The `username` field is no longer accessible with the Graph API v2.0. There are at least 5-10 questions on this on StackOverflow today.

Look at the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Problem is its just a small static website.. I liked the fact i just had a URL to their profile pictures.. But if I understand the docs correctly Facebook just took that feature down? :( Guess I'll just download the pictures manually then...